# retrieving .data without using .each

Tags: jquery

If I set some arbitrary number of elements with a certain class. I can get at these just by doing:

```
$('.class_I_want', parentELEMref ).show();
```

there you go, I just showed all elements with that class under a certain element.

BUT, if I build those elements, and add something like :

```
$(this_elem).data('myval','true');
```

I cannot do the same thing ala:

```
$( parentELEMref ).data('myval').show();
```

or

```
$(parentELEMref ).not("[data-myvar*='true']").show();
```

Now, if I $.each it, its fine. But I want to be able to just do it without the loop, possible?

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
$(parentELEMref).find(":not([data-myvar='true'])").show();
```

The `.not()` method operates on the elements in the jQuery collection it's applied to, it doesn't search the children of it -- you have to use `.find()`.

This doesn't work:

```
$( parentELEMref ).data('myval').show();
```

because `.data('myval')` returns the value of the data, it doesn't return a jQuery collection.

However, you also need to change how you set the data. You need to use `.attr()` rather than `.data()`. When you first access the data of an element, jQuery will pull it from the `data-XXX` attribute, but from then on it caches it in internal jQuery memory. Assigning the data doesn't modify the attribute in the DOM, and that's what the `[data-myvar]` selector looks for. So change:

```
$(this_elem).data('myval','true');
```

to:

```
$(this_elem).attr('data-myval','true');
```

and make sure you use `.attr()` consistently for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the data value as an attribute `$( parentELEMref ).attr('data-myvar');`
Then use the selector `$([data-myvar="true"])`

Answer (score 0):

that is because `$(this_elem).data('myval','true');` is adding the data attribute to every element in the selection **not** the selection itself (which is a transient object with no real permanence anyway).

to select and `show()` the elements under `parentELEMref` that have that attribute set to false (or not set at all) do this:

```
$(':not([data-myvar="true"])', parentELEMref).show();
```